# Apache ActiveMQ Server-to-Server connection

Tags: messaging, activemq-classic, mq

Our company now uses Websphere MQ to facilitate communication with our business partners, but we're evaluating migration to ActiveMQ. I've read some documentation and articles and haven't found particular option we need - server-to-server connections.

Apache MQ has notion of broker networks, but as I understood it's more of a clustering then site-to-site communication.

We need to have a local message broker (AMQ server) and a remote one. Local is used by our applications and remote one is used by our partner's apps, there is a limited number of remote queues (on partner's broker) we need to put messages to and we also have some queues on our side which our partners have to put messages to.
Is there a possibility to implement this workload with ApacheMQ?

Feel free to ask questions if I'm a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can setup security to protect queues and topics for specific partners on the same network of brokers...see http://activemq.apache.org/security.html

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ supports a variety of broker network topologies that allow for this and many other types of functionality.  You should have a look this documentation on [distributed queue](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html) and also read over the docs on [broker networks](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html).

Comment: I've read all that. Either documentation is incomplete, or AMQ just can't do what we need. The broker networks and distributed queues are a clustering solution to load balance messages between [geographically or otherwise] separated brokers. This presents HUGE security problems.
Let's imagine we have two partners - A and B. we need to send messages to queue a.receive.q and b.receive.q on A and B respectively. From what I read A actually can subscribe to b.receive.q and vice versa. Also, if some malicious employee launches local consumer on a.receive.q, it won't be sent over the network at all.

Comment: If networks are to complicated for you then perhaps the JMS-to-JMS bridge is more what you need, see: http://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge.html